# what should i do about the hearing voices in my head?

Tags: spirituality, spiritual

I am suffering from hearing voices problem every second (similar to schizophernia) since 2020. the voices are saying that they are ghosts or spirits.
someone send them as to harm me. they ghosts are talking one after the others

True incidents in 2020 :

1. the ghosts fools me with changing voices where ever i go and whom i talk with it will imitates them and scolds me.
   At first i belive them as real people.
2. after few days I saw a black ghost at the evening comes towards me in my street i didn't fear at that moment.
3. I saw my lecturer madam face changes in another face directly with my naked eye, and another face turns into some other face in my college. at night time a saw a small girl become young adult in lively. (kanikattu in telugu)
4. They make noise somedays i won't sleep at night.
5. Make me get bad night dreams continously and alterntively days.
   6)They impose thought on my brain by removing people cloths. i got fooled as it was me.
6. they make noise during reading and exams.

2021:

1)Every night my body become loose , i loose my physical strenght still it is happening.
2)They make me pain in my muscles and various parts of my body still happening.
3)Touching my chest sometimes and my private parts organs.
4)sometimes my figers got moving without my sense.

2022:

1. I got to know they were ghost as they told.
2. They move my brain nerves so that i'm unable to recollect the name.
3. they blocking my brain sometimes.

and Lot More things happening around me

what should i do?
is there any prayers for protection?

Comment: You should immediately consult a professional Tantrk... You won't get any help from this site.

Comment: This is not a question about Hinduism. You should see a doctor asap.

Answer (score 0):

You have some doubts that someone is against you. You might either be having a psychiatric issue or it might be a genuine issue which we're not aware of. Do Sathyanarayan pooja at home, take a vacation break, stay away from mobile and social media, go to your parents house and be around your mother, meet up with some good old friends, try having a pet, cut off negative contacts from your life, try focussing on your fav hobbies.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion.

See **most of these kind of cases are psychiatric**, no real ghosts will be there. This is becuase some chemicals in the brain have imbalance. So you should consult a psychiatrist first. **This is a must**. Modern medicine can do wonders in this regard. Visit a psychiatrist and follow their advice. Avoid Sugar, it is linked to mental disorders and also avoid Gluten(Wheat and Barley). When such things happen, **first** it must be examined medically and then spiritually.

**In rare cases, it may be some affliction of spirits** etc. For this one can try to do some stuff.

1. Wear Rudraksha mala. [Isha rudraksha](https://www.ishalife.com/in/panchamukhi-rudraksha-mala-7-5-mm-bead) from Sadhguru is good brand. You can also order Devi [Linga Bhairavi Pendant](https://www.ishalife.com/in/linga-bhairavi-copper-pendant-medium) with [String](https://www.ishalife.com/in/linga-bhairavi-pendant-rope) and [Abhaya Sutra](https://www.ishalife.com/in/devi-abhaya-sutra). All this is said to be consecrated and is believed to help cultivate positive energy. This is quite affordable, all of this will cost less than 800/- as of today.
2. **External Cleanliness**: Make sure you take shower often, preferably daily and keep your place clean and hygienic. You can use Neem or Tulsi or Mysore Sandal soap.
   **Internal Cleanliness**: Eat Sattvik food and every morning try to take Neem and Turmeric Balls along with luke warm honey. This is said to purify the blood and digestive tract. Make sure your digestive fire and digestion process is good, by using Ginger and Jeera and small amounts of Black salt and Triphala.
3. Burn **Loban** and **Guggulu** dhoop in your home daily at morning and evening. It helps positive energy.
4. Visit Lord Hanuman temple every Saturday and or Tuesday. Apply Sindoor or Kumkum daily. Peferably which is collected from temple after applying to Lord Hanuman.
   In that temple if they give Tayata or locket, wear it and if they give thread tie it to your wrist.
5. Chant Hanuman Chalisa, facing North or East, preferably after bath at Sun rise and after washing face, hands and feet at Sun set. Preferably do this after lighting Loban and Guggulu dhoop. Preferably 11 times daily.

> Bhoot pisach Nikat nahin aavai Mahavir jab naam sunavai
>
> All the
> ghosts, demons, and evil forces keep away, with the sheer mention of
> your great name, O'Mahaveer!!
>
> [Hanuman Chalisa](https://www.thehansindia.com/life-style/spiritual/hanuman-chalisa-explained-in-english-616309)

Combine both of these, visit to psychiatrist and spiritual practices.

---

You can, try to consult a Pandit or a Pujari, make sure he is not fake or fraud and is asking for huge amount of money.

You can also use ayurvedic medications like medhya rasayanas like Brahmi, Mandukaparni, Mukta Pishti, Ashwagandha etc. **Do not self medicate, consult an ayurvedic doctor.**